# Ansible: How to create a user and ansible become that user

Tags: ansible

I want to create a user “deploy” via ansible, set ssh keys, group permissions and then ansible be set to that user.

How do I do this?

Comment: You don't say what that you tried and on what you're failing to do. Please look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use user module for creating user "deploy"
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/user_module.html

and in next task:

```
become: yes
become_user: deploy
```